# VBA-excel double loop condition

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working in excel vba, though my programming is simply terrible. I would like to perform the following functionality. I have 2 ranges of data:

One range (a1:a10) refers to the variable that need to be checked against the other range (b1:b250). The condition the variable is checking against should be that if the variable is smaller (<) than the values in the range (b1:b250), then it should spit out the variable, otherwise is should show "0".

Therefore a = 1 to 10 should check against all the values of b = 1 to 250 as if the loop should run 2500 times to ensure all the values in range (a1:a10) have checked against range (b1:b250). Please let me know if you can help or what other information is necessary.

Comment: Have you tried some code? An example of code you have tried will allow us to give you more helpful pointers. (there are several examples of code in this forum that will provide a good jumping off point for this question)

Comment: if you dont care about order of range b1:b250 you can sort this range and then compare only smalest value. This will save you a buch of time. If you care about order of this range, copy it to some temporary column first.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that without any loops. An SQL query works for you. Here is how you can do that.

```
Sub tadaaa()

Dim con As Object, rs As Object
Dim query As String, query1 As String
Dim connector As String
Dim address As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")


    Set con = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("adodb.recordset")

    address = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    connector = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source=" & _
             address & ";extended properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;hdr=yes"""

    con.Open connector


    query = "select Defender from [sheet1$] where Defender < "
                            'Source sheet

    For i = 2 To sht.Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        query1 = query & sht.Cells(i, 2).Value

        Set rs = con.Execute(query1) 'Execute the query

        'Recording query results to any sheet you want.
        sht.Cells(6500, 2 * i).End(3).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs

        sht.Cells(1, 2 * i).Value = rs.Fields(0).Name & " vs A" & i

        Set rs = Nothing

        query1 = Empty

    Next


Set con = Nothing


End Sub
```

It is my initial sheet. Your B values are in A column and A values are in B column.
[image]

And this is the after vba code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, though there is an error with the "a = Application.Min(Range("B1:B255"))" - Run time error '6', overflow. The example that I used above, was just to explain the logic. The values that the variable a is checking against has 5218936 values. Also, if the variable is greater that the value, then it should spit out the variable as it is, I don't believe this has been included in your code?

Comment: So I managed o sort out the error, it was decimal values in which I changed the "Dim a As Long" instead of Interger. Though the code does not loop through all the values of B1:255, only through the first 10 line items. I need it to loop or check through all the 255 values. Please assist.

Comment: the code finds the minimum number on B1:255 and assign it to 'a'. then in the question, you said, there is 10 data on range("A"). That's why it compares only 10 number. You can change the number on For loop 10 to any number you want.

Comment: Each of the 10 numbers should be checked against each of the values in range B1:B255. Therefore the loop is 10x255 = 2550 in which not only 10 values will be output as in your code. There might be 2000 outputs of which any of the values in A1:A10 is greater than B1:B255. Ex. A1 can be greater than B4, B6, B200 and B224 in which 4 outputs will need to be given for one value that was checked.

Comment: Now I see. Sorry I didn't understand exactly before. So I think you can use ADO SQL connection to get rid of all loops.

Comment: After the connection your query should be like "select * from [tablename$] where 'B columns name' > A1(value)" I'll try to edit my answer as soon as possible. I am on Ubuntu now and dont have an excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ali SM for showing an excellent, but less known way!
Before Ali, I would have suggested one more Loop-Less approach:

```
Sub WithoutLoop()

Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "=""Vs Examiner ""&OFFSET(R2C2,COLUMN()-5,0)"
Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OFFSET(R2C2,COLUMN()-5,0)<RC4,OFFSET(R2C2,COLUMN()-5,0),0)"
Range("E1").Copy
Range("E1", Range("E1").Offset(0, 9)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
Range("E2").Copy
Range("E2", Range("E2").Offset(2500, 9)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

End Sub
```

Before Macro:

[image]

After Macro:

[image]